# Shared resources problem with multithreading in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml

So i'm working on a simple WPF app that should read informations from a "dedicated page " on our LAN and output them more efficiently. So now i'm trying to make the labels content update automatically after an ip to get datas from is selected. The plan is to basically refresh the page every minute or so to update the output.
Problem is I tryed a lot of solutions about multithreading but still get the same error : InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
basically what i understand from that is that the mainWindows thread owns the labels' contents so that i can't update them after reading from said file/string.

Here's my xaml for the window:

```
  <Window x:Class="PartCountBello.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
          xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PartCountBello"
          mc:Ignorable="d"
          Title="Controllo Macchine" Height="337.42" Width="366.586" 
  ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
      <Grid Margin="0,10,2,12">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ComboBox x:Name="cmbNomiMacchine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  Margin="44,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="22" 
  SelectionChanged="cmbNomiMacchine_SelectionChanged"/>
          <Label x:Name="lblNomeDato" Content="PartCount :" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,162,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  Height="26" Width="129"/>
          <Label x:Name="lblPartCount" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="178,162,0,0" Height="26" Width="144" 
  RenderTransformOrigin="0.071,0.731"/>
          <Label x:Name="lblSelectInfos" Content="Selezionare macchina" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  Width="129" Height="26"/>
          <Label x:Name="lblLavoro" Content="Mansione : " 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  Width="129"/>
          <Label x:Name="lblMansione" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  Margin="178,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="144"/>
          <Button x:Name="btnRefresh" Content="Aggiorna" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="247,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  Width="75" Height="22" Click="btnRefresh_Click"/>
          <Label x:Name="lblMoreInfos" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  Margin="10,241,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="339" Height="35"/>

      </Grid>
  </Window>
```

and here is my mainWindows Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace PartCountBello
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<string> datas = new List<string> { };      //list that contains machines names and relatives ips. each ip is in the previous index...
                                                        //respect to the machine. 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();                       //creates the file reader we 're using to...
                datas = rf.getListFromFile("MyIPsFile");   //get all our datas from our file.. Not posting the real file name here cuz you never know. still contains only the ips to connect to.
                for(int i = 2;i<=datas.Count-1;i+=3)
                {
                    cmbNomiMacchine.Items.Add(datas[i]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMoreInfos.Content = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            { 
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// when the selection is changed to an item it will update the labels contents through a method in the class activityChecker.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void cmbNomiMacchine_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            updateLabelsContent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// gets the index the item selected in the combobox has in the file to pass it to the fileread and get the ip.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private int getSelectedItemIndex(int index)
        {
            int FIRST_REAL_INDEX = 2;
            int realIndex;
            if (index == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return realIndex=FIRST_REAL_INDEX+index*2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// checks if the machine we are trying to connect to is on, if so updates the dedicated lables' content, else prints a simple message down below.
        /// </summary>
        private void updateLabelsContent()
        {
            string toShow;//the auxiliary string we are going to use to output on labels.
            ActivityChecker ac = new ActivityChecker();
            lblMoreInfos.Content = "";
            if (getSelectedItemIndex(cmbNomiMacchine.SelectedIndex) != 0)
            {
                if (PingHost(datas[getSelectedItemIndex(cmbNomiMacchine.SelectedIndex) - 1]))
                {
                    toShow = ac.getPartCount(datas[getSelectedItemIndex(cmbNomiMacchine.SelectedIndex)]);
                    lblPartCount.Content = toShow;
                    toShow = ac.getJob(datas[getSelectedItemIndex(cmbNomiMacchine.SelectedIndex)]);
                    lblMansione.Content = toShow;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMoreInfos.Content = "La macchina è al momento spenta.";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMansione.Content = "";
                lblPartCount.Content = "";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// updates the content of the machine dedicated labels.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                updateLabelsContent(); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// allows to verify if the machine we are trying to connect to is on before we actually try to, avoids some freezes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nameOrAddress"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
        {
            bool pingable = false;
            Ping pinger = new Ping();
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
                pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            }
            catch (PingException)
            {
                // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
            }
            return pingable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you test with a copy of file on your local disk.. to see if functional.   This test could eliminate rights or authority problem on file stored on Lan?

Comment: Laziest way: look into SynchronizationContext

Comment: @Frenchy yeah the problem is not with the file reading the problem is just about labels not willing to be shared within 2 threads. the file and the reading part work fine.

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea and what should i do into the sychronizationContext? im quite a newbie in multithreaded programming so something more explicative would really help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found a solution.

added this to mainwindows.cs:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// private method that manages the thread for the automatic update.
        /// </summary>
        private void updateLabelsContentThread()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { updateLabelsContent(); }));
            }
        }
```

and changed the event method for machine selection to this.

```
/// <summary>
        /// when the selection is changed to an item it will update the labels contents through a method in the class activityChecker.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void cmbNomiMacchine_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            updateLabelsContent();
            Thread t = new Thread(updateLabelsContentThread);
            t.Start();

        }
```

works perfectly for me, leaving this here in case it helps someone.

Comment: glad you found a solution :)

Comment: @AlexandruClonțea still would be cool to understand how you would ve fixed it with SynchronizationContext. i looked into some explanations of it but couldn't really figure it out.

Comment: I posted an answer right after you! Let me know what makes sense or not. I am still wondering why there was a crossthread operation exception in the first place, perhaps offscreen code... or me tired yesterday

Answer (score 0):

I am not advocating this WinForms-like approach, there are probably better solutions using bindings, but it would require a lot of changes. If you need to do it this way and now:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ....

    private readonly SynchronizationContext uiContext;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //controls created on a specific thread can only be modified by that thread.
        //(99.99999%) of the time controls are created and modified on the UI thread
        //SynchronizationContext provides a way to capture and delegate work to the UI thread (it provides more functionality than this, but in your case this is what interests you)
        //We capture the UI Synchronization Context so that we can queue items for execution to the UI thread. We know this is the UI thread because we are in the constructor for our main window
        uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        ....
    }

    private void cmbNomiMacchine_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateOnUIThread();
    }

    ...............

    ///I Chose to write another method for clarity, feel free to rework the code anyway you like. Ideally you want to only delegate short work to the UI thread (say textbox.Text = "". This is just here to show the concept
   private void UpdateOnUIThread()
   {
       //Post is asynchronous so will give controll back immediately. If you want synchronous operation, use Send
       uiContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback((o) => { updateLabelsContent(); }), null);
   }

   ..............
}
```

}

Comment: ok  i did some experiments with the synchronization context before your answer. im glad i figured out that i had to get the current context after the initializecomponet. im still not sure i got what post does in this scenario but im gonna do some experiments and figure it out :) thank you :)

Comment: @Cicciopalla010 Post means that the calling thread can carry on with its non-UI work. If you had called .Send instead of .Post on the synchronization context, the calling thread would be blocked, waiting for the UI update operation to finish.